# jQuery target next hidden div that's on a different level

Tags: jquery, html, css

**DESIRED RESULT**
I have a table full of data. In a `<td>` of each row is a modal trigger. I want that modal trigger to pop open a hidden modal that resides outside of the `<td>`, but still within the table (after its closing `</tr>`). Clicking each trigger *only* opens its hidden `<div>`.

**PROBLEM**
I can't seem to target the hidden `<div>` which is up a level and a sibling to the `<tr>`. I've tried so many variations of .next, .parent, .closest, and .find - but to no avail. I can get it to open if the hidden `<div>` is directly after the `</td>` with the below jQuery, but I don't want the hidden `<div>` there...I want it after the `</tr>` like below. Could someone please enlighten me?

**CODEPEN**
[codepen](http://codepen.io/zuhloobie/pen/aNVpwO) (updated to reflect chosen answer from guest271314)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <!-- ROW 1 -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="quickViewTrigger">MODAL TRIGGER 1</div>
            </td>
            <td>misc cell 1</td>
            <td>misc cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <div class="quickViewContainer">
            <div id="quickViewCloseButton" class="close" style="margin-right:10px;"><span></span></div>
                <div class="quickViewTitle">MODAL 1</div>
                <div class="quickViewBody">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In lacus dolor, vestibulum id fermentum molestie, tempor in ligula. Sed quis leo a erat vehicula hendrerit. Morbi ac elementum risus. Donec pretium euismod sapien quis sagittis. Phasellus sit amet
volutpat sem.</div>
        </div>
        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="quickViewTrigger">MODAL TRIGGER 2</div>
            </td>
            <td>misc cell 1</td>
            <td>misc cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <div class="quickViewContainer">
            <div id="quickViewCloseButton" class="close" style="margin-right:10px;"><span></span></div>
            <div class="quickViewTitle">MODAL 2</div>
            <div class="quickViewBody">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In lacus dolor, vestibulum id fermentum molestie, tempor in ligula. Sed quis leo a erat vehicula hendrerit. Morbi ac elementum risus. Donec pretium euismod sapien quis sagittis. Phasellus sit amet
volutpat sem.</div>
        </div>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    // OPEN MODAL ON TRIGGER CLICK
    $(".quickViewTrigger").on('click', function () {
        var $quickview = $(this).next(".quickViewContainer");
        $quickview.dequeue().stop().slideToggle(500, "easeInOutQuart");
        $(".quickViewContainer").not($quickview).slideUp(200, "easeInOutQuart");
    });

    // CLOSE MODAL WITH MODAL CLOSE BUTTON
    $(".close").click(function() {
        $(".quickViewContainer").fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Comment: `<div> which is up a level and a sibling to the <tr>` the sibling or tr is another tr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>` is not a valid child node of `<table>` element

Comment: So the reason why it was working for me after the </td> is because at that instance, it is an allowed child. But once it becomes a direct child of <table>, it breaks due to your explanation?

Comment: @chris If you open `console` at codepen and inspect `<table>` element, `<div>` elements are moved within `DOM` to previous element siblings of `<table>`. You could wrap `<div>` elements in `<tr>` elements then use selector `$(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".quickViewContainer");`. See [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#Usage_context) at "Permitted content"

Comment: wrapping the hidden `<div>` in another `<tr><td>` is an acceptable solution and it works. I've updated the codepen. Thank you for your direction :)

Comment: @chris You could substitute `.closest("tr")` for `.parent().parent()` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZVmXv

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I tried so many combinations, my head was spinning. CodePen edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. 
[codepen](http://codepen.io/Almask/pen/XdzRMY)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="quickViewTrigger" data-modal="1">MODAL TRIGGER 1</div>
        </td>
        <td>misc cell 1</td>
        <td>misc cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="quickViewTrigger" data-modal="2">MODAL TRIGGER 2</div>
        </td>
        <td>misc cell 1</td>
        <td>misc cell 2</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<div class="modals">
    <div class="quickViewContainer" id="modal1">
        <div class="close" style="margin-right:10px;"><span></span></div>
        <div class="quickViewTitle">MODAL 1</div>
        <div class="quickViewBody">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In lacus dolor, vestibulum id fermentum molestie, tempor in ligula. Sed quis leo a erat vehicula hendrerit. Morbi ac elementum risus. Donec pretium euismod sapien quis sagittis. Phasellus sit
            amet volutpat sem.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quickViewContainer" id="modal2">
        <div class="close" style="margin-right:10px;"><span></span></div>
        <div class="quickViewTitle">MODAL 2</div>
        <div class="quickViewBody">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In lacus dolor, vestibulum id fermentum molestie, tempor in ligula. Sed quis leo a erat vehicula hendrerit. Morbi ac elementum risus. Donec pretium euismod sapien quis sagittis. Phasellus sit
            amet volutpat sem.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    // OPEN MODAL ON TRIGGER CLICK
    $(".quickViewTrigger").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $quickview = $("#modal" + $(this).data('modal'));
        $quickview.dequeue().stop().slideToggle(500, "easeInOutQuart");
        $(".quickViewContainer").not($quickview).slideUp(200, "easeInOutQuart");
    });
    // CLOSE MODAL WITH MODAL CLOSE BUTTON
    $(".close").click(function() {
        $(".quickViewContainer").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

**css:**

```
.modals .quickViewContainer{
    display:none;
}
.close{
    position:absolute;
    right:3px;
    top:3px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Div is not valid child of table, so move it to another div.

Comment: I knew that was an option (and it works), but due to the structure of the table and entering data, it is valuable to have the hidden div's next to the trigger rather than all at the bottom. Several rows in this table.

Comment: can you place hidden modals inside <td> with the trigger? Something like 
<td>
<div class="quickViewTrigger">modal</div>
<div class="quickViewContainer" id="modal1">
        <div class="close" style="margin-right:10px;"><span></span></div>
        <div class="quickViewTitle">MODAL 1</div>
        <div class="quickViewBody">lorem</div>
    </div>
</td>

Answer (score 0):

## Here's a little something. . .

***[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xm949w1q/2/)***

I didn't finish it all the way, but I think you'll be able to come up with something from here. I've included jQuery 1.12, and here is a simple function I use to hide/unhide the modal.

All you have to do is figure out how to get it to be hidden by default, and tweak to your liking.

```
$("#triggerOne").click(function(){
                $("#modalOne").fadeToggle("slow", "linear")
});
```

Replace that div with a button, and assign id's to each button. The way I have it you'd have to write new functions for each modal trigger, but if you used a class it would hide/unhide them all at the same time.

I'm still new to js/jquery, so I'm sure there's a better way still to do it.

Hopefully this points you in a good direction :)

Comment: I see now that it's putting the content above the table as well.. let me see if I can fix that

Comment: position: absolute; might get you close to what you wantr: https://jsfiddle.net/3u85cy6e/2/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(".quickViewTrigger").on('click', function () {

       var rowIndex = $('.container table tr').index($(this).closest('tr'));
       //console.log(rowIndex);
        var $quickview = $(".quickViewContainer").eq(rowIndex);

     // console.log($quickview);

        $quickview.dequeue().stop().slideToggle(500, "easeInOutQuart");
        $(".quickViewContainer").not($quickview).slideUp(200, "easeInOutQuart");
    });
    // CLOSE MODAL WITH MODAL CLOSE BUTTON
    $(".close").click(function() {
        $(".quickViewContainer").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

https://jsbin.com/xipafet/1/edit?html,css,js,output

only output
https://output.jsbin.com/xipafet/1